# SQL find records based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a users table with primary key of `id`, I have a foreign table called `friends` which only has two fields (`userid1, userid2`). This allows us to create any kind of relationship between different users (one to many, one to one, etc). A user can appear in either column and both columns are equal. IOW, a single entry per relationship.

How can I pull all of the friends that a given user `id` has. Say Jonny, has 3 friends and his user `id` is `16`... should my sql query look like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   db.users 
       JOIN db.friends 
         ON db.users.id = db.friends.userid1 
            AND db.users.id = 16
```

Hopefully, this is clear. Also, if possible, can I exclude Jonny from the result set?

This query, as listed gies me the following:

```
id      name    uuid                       birthday        userid1  userid2
16  jonny   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP    1967-04-27 01:00:00     1         2
16  jonny   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP    1967-04-27 01:00:00     1         3
```

This is pretty close, except I want his friends, not jonny

---

Thanks guys, so I got it to work thanks to you. Here is the final working query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.users
WHERE db.users.id IN
(
  SELECT db.friends.userid2 as id FROM db.friends WHERE db.friends.userid1 = 16
    union
  SELECT db.friends.userid1 as id FROM db.friends WHERE db.friends.userid2 = 16
)
```

which gives me:

```
id      name    uuid                       birthday 
2   robin   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP    1967-04-27 01:00:00
3   gary    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP    1967-04-27 01:00:00
```

Comment: Execute the query you proposed and tell us whether the result meets your needs (and if not, in which way did it fail).

Comment: jonnies friends are the users with `id` 2 and 3. So you already have jonnies firends. Where is the problem?

Comment: Yes. The friends are what we want. I really don't need to two extra columns either, but that's fine.

Comment: If you don't need columns, don't specify that you need them in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a sub query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT userid2 as id FROM db.friends WHERE userid1 = 16
)
```

Comment: This is very close, if I could get it to work both directions so that a user id can be in either column and still give us the list, then I would have it.

Comment: So just do an OR in the sub query. "WHERE userid1 = 16 OR userid2 = 16"

Answer (score 1):

Add the condition for the `user.id` to your `where` clause at the end:

```
Select * From users
INNER JOIN friends on
users.id = friends.userid1
Where users.id = 16
```

Also, I would use an `Inner Join` which will return all records from `users` only where there is a match in `friends`

Comment: In MySQL, a plain `JOIN` keyword implies `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: The condition `users.id = 16` might as well be part of the `ON` clause as in the query that the OP proposed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I was just detailing my answer, not suggesting that the two were different

Comment: @Oswald Is there really any difference in this example? I tend to add the condition as part of the `on` clause when the condition refers to the joined table. In this case it did not

Comment: @Evan The `WHERE` condition is evaluated very late in the query processing, much later than the `ON` clause. The `users.id = 16` condition has a very low selectivity, narrowing the possible results very fast. It's good to do this early. The optimizer should (IMHO) notice this and move `users.id = 16` into the `ON` clause, so there should not be a noticable difference. But if there is no difference, your answer only repeats the query that the OP proposed. And if there is a difference, the query that the OP proposed is faster.

Comment: @Oswald You're right, but that is only because this question has gone through 100's of edits since the original posting. The question is much different now.

Comment: @Evan Yep, you're right, the original version of the question did not include the `users.id = 16` condition at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter on the friends table, not the users table.

```
SELECT friends.*
FROM friends
INNER JOIN users
  ON friends.userid2 = users.id
WHERE friends.userid1 = 16
```

If you just need the friend ID's then there is not reason to join at all

```
SELECT userid2
FROM friends
WHERE userid1 = 16
```

Comment: The id of the target sought can be in either column. IOW, jonny can be in column 1 or column 2.

Comment: So you don't add a two-way relationship into that table? I.e when user 1 friends user 100 there a two records entered `1|100` and `100|1`? That will make you life a little more difficult when it comes to querying as you haven't really defined a user column and a friend column.  You are probably going to force yourself to do sub-selects or to union the results of two queries.

Comment: Nope, if I do it right, there will only be one entry. Should I do two?

Comment: It depends: do you have a case of not wasting storage with rows and indexes? If not, double relationships ease many queries...

Comment: @MickeyKawick I guess best approach here may come down to yourr data access patterns.  You are going to need to union the result of two queries or perhaps do a subselect, which might make the data lookup take longer, however on the other hand if you make two entries, you would need to do two inserts for add "friend connections".  So you might need to determine which actions are most frequent in your system and optimize for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a list of friends ids:

`SELECT U
    FROM DB.USERS U
    WHERE U.ID IN ( SELECT F.USERID2 FROM DB.FRIENDS F WHERE F.USERID1 = 16)`

Comment: The OP does not want that according to his question "How can I pull all of the friends that a given user id has."

Comment: I considered that either relationship is bidirectional or is asking for outgoing relationships

Comment: Ah yeah now that I've refreshed the page and seen the results I understand his requirements!